# SQL: One table referencing another table to return a third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not a SQL guy so this question may be very easy for many of you. But I have two tables and I want a SQL statement to return me a third table by combining values of table 1 and 2.

I have the following tables:

Table PRODUCT:

```
Column NAME
Column CAMPAIGNS
```

Table CAMPAIGN:

```
Column ID 
Column NAME
```

With the following values:

Product:

```
Nike Sneakers | 1 2 3
```

Campaign:

```
1 | Red Shoes
2 | No laces 
3 | Velcro 
4 | White Shoes
```

Instead of the campaign IDs, I want the campaign Names to returned with product.

Result Table:

```
Nike Sneaker | Red shoes, No laces, Velcro
```

How would you guys achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to look at normalising your database and creating a many to many table between Product and Campaign. There is no easy way to join the value `1 2 3` in product to 3 seperate records in Campaign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is create a many to many joins (1 product can have many campaigns and 1 campaign can have many products). You cannot do this by storing all the campaigns in one column. The right way to do it is to create a many to many join, which means you need to create a join table:

```
Table PRODUCT:
Column ID
Column NAME

Table CAMPAIGN:
Column ID 
Column NAME

Table PRODUCTCAMPAIGN
Column ProductID
Column CampaignID


Product: 
1 | Nike Sneakers

Campaign:
1 | Red Shoes
2 | No laces 
3 | Velcro 
4 | White Shoes

ProductCampaign
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
```

You can then do

```
SELECT Product.ID, Campaign.Name
FROM   Product
INNER JOIN ProductCampaign
ON         ProductCampaign.ProductID = Product.ID
INNER JOIN Campaign
ON         Campaign.ID = ProductCampaign.CampaignID
```

That should give you:

```
Nike Sneaker | Red shoes
Nike Sneaker | No laces
Nike Sneaker | Velcro
```

You should then be able to make them comma seperated. I don't have MySQL in front of me to help you with that one. I think GROUP_CONCAT should work for you.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thanks! Now if I wanted to insert a product (Nike Sneaker) into 3 campaigns how would I do that?

Comment: Greg, with SQL statement will not return products that aren't in campaigns how do return those as well?

Comment: If you want to add products to campaigns just add records to ProductCampaign table. To get all products make it a left join between product and ProductCampaign